# Javascript alert is being prematurely closed by slow Youtube link loading. How do I fix this w/out putting video source in my script.js?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

5th day coding, 1st day using Javascript.

I need to put an alert on a page using Javascript and then pulling that Javascript code from a separate file. I have successfully done this, *however*, the alert is automatically closed out as soon as the page opens because the Youtube link loads so slowly.

I **had**:

HTML

```
<iframe 
width="901" 
height="507" 
src="YoutubeLink"
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
alert('Welcome to the page!')
```

A developer in the bootcamp class I'm in said I could use the code below - which works, except that he also said this could cause problems in the future AND the page itself doesn't load at all until you close out of the alert.

HTML

```
<iframe 
id="video"
width="901" 
height="507" 
allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
alert('Welcome!')
var video = document.getElementById('video')
video.src="YoutubeLink"
```

I need to keep the Youtube link in the HTML code, but I can't just put the script line above the iframe and the above code works for displaying the alert and forcing a user to close it, but the rest of the page doesn't load behind it.

Any suggestions? Please be thorough in explanations as I'm still really new.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can't make much sense of your questions. How does the loading time close an alert? "_AND the page itself doesn't load at all until you close out of the alert._" Isn't that the goal when you said "_I need to put an alert on a page using Javascript and then pulling that Javascript code from a separate file._" Please clarify what is wrong with the code you provided, what it is supposed to do and if possible add a [mcve] using the `<>` button in the editor.

Comment: Also confused by what your expected result is. Are you just looking to call your alert after the page is fully loaded? `window.onload = function() { alert('Welcome!'); }`

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure code executes after your page loads, you can use something like:

```
window.onload = function() { alert('Welcome!'); }
```

If using jQuery, you can read up on [document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! ElliotSchmelliot, thank you for providing that. I figured it was something simple, but I wasn't using proper terms when Googling I suppose.

Apologies, for making the question a bit confusing and thank you very much for the responses.

I have the Youtube embed code in my HTML file and the only thing in my Javascript is the window.onload.

This makes it so the entire page loads for the user and then the alert displays as was intended.

(Please let me know if this is not the appropriate way to resolve the question on here.)